# Play sound through a specific channel Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, audio

I'm currently looking for a way to emit a specific sound through the Alarm channel in Android. Currently I'm using the [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) plugin but it does not provide a channel settings. I want the volume of my sound to be managed by the alarm slider of the OS.
Does anyone have any idea of how I could achieve this, by either using a plugin or describing how I could implement it natively ?

Thanks in advance